# Is there a way to send GET and POST requests via NetBeans without an external library?

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-httpclient-4.x

I've recently picked up NetBeans as what looks like a comprehensive IDE for writing a GUI application. What struck me as unusual was that it didn't come with any built-in support for creating and reading responses to simple GET and POST requests. While this *seems* to be because it's aimed at a crowd interested in writing web services in NetBeans, I was hoping there would be some basic request and response functionality in the program regardless.

Is there a library included to serve this purpose already? (If there is, I must be using the wrong methods to look for it.)

Presently, I've downloaded and utilised Apache's HTTPClient and IOUtils, which *work* but look like they may be redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out
**For GET**

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();  //connecting to url
c.setRequestMethod("GET");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));  //stream to resource
String str;
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)   //reading data
   responsestring += str+"\n";//process the response and save it in some string or so
in.close();  //closing stream
```

**For POST**

```
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

con.setRequestMethod("POST");

String urlParameters = ..;

con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    res.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
```

Comment: It was awesome until I needed to jump on an IOUtil to get it to work... and then I bit the bullet. Your examples worked, though!

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans doesn't provide you with any java classes. All the classes come from the java libraries, NetBeans is just the IDE that lets you do your work conveniently.

So to translate your question: No, the standard java libraries don't provide you with a useful http client other than [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html).

The Apache HTTPClient library is a good approach, althoug for basic GETs and POSTs, it is far too complex. Coding GETs and POSTs yourself is pretty easy, though, take a look at the [htt protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Example_session).

Comment: Well, NetBeans for Java plus whatever awesomeness it happens to offer under JDK 7. I should have specified... I'd forgotten NB didn't come equipped with Java.